# What is the design system of gumroad?

Tags: design, terminology, learning

I am learning web development, and in the process of taking inspiration for UI online, I came across gumroad.com. Its design is bright, colorful, blocky, doodly, etc.

I want to learn about this design, but due to my lack of knowledge of design terminology, I do not what is it called. A friend told me, its called outline design, or bubble design; but Google search with those keywords is not very promising.

Randomly searching on google gave suggestions like "brutalism", "bauhaus style" etc.

I am really confused because I do not know what any of this is called, where to even begin google search, and how to even ask questions about it.

I would really appreciate if someone can explain what the design theme of gumroad.com is called, if design theme is even the correct vocabulary, and where can I learn and study that design style.

Comment: Since you asked about terminology, [a design system is a set of standards around specific components and patterns](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/design-systems-101/). What you're asking about is a design style, which is more of a general look or aesthetic. The design _style_ Gumroad uses is neubrutalism, but [their actual design system doesn't appear to have a name](https://gumroad.com/blog/behind-gumroads-new-design-system).

Answer (score 6):

I am sharing few Figma and Medium resource links below, related to your required design style, which may help you get started.

- [Neubrutalism Landing Page Design](https://www.figma.com/community/file/1106936342025545272)
- [Neubrutalism Icons Set](https://www.figma.com/community/file/1092848226893690641)
- [Neubrutalism UI](https://www.figma.com/community/file/1123166854111832208)
- [Advanced Figma tricks, Neobrutalism, UX sketching, the phases of research](https://uxdesign.cc/advanced-figma-tricks-neobrutalism-ux-sketching-the-phases-of-research-3af9ee7541ae)
- [What is the Neubrutalism Web Design Trend?](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/what-is-the-neubrutalism-web-design-trend--cms-41576)
- [Neubrutalism in Web Design: Embracing the Ugly](https://www.svgator.com/blog/neubrutalism-in-web-design-embracing-the-ugly/)
- [Neubrutalism style in UX: a twist on the dominant modern minimalist](https://uxdesign.cc/why-im-excited-about-the-neubrutalism-style-in-web-design-4ab800c2bb80)

Answer (score 2):

Okay after 2 hours of Google searches, I found the word, it is **neubrutalism**!

Comment: The question remaining now is that, where can I learn about it? Is there a proper book to learn different designs etc?